# Distributed computing project?

Tags: windows-7, windows, graphics-card, cpu, cpu-usage

I've tried seti@home and folding. But are there any other good ones that might have better luck actually making a difference?

I don't want to contribute to a project that is going to use the results for profit, and set@home is just such a long shot. Folding at home hasn't yet made any discoveries as i know either.

Comment: Maybe [WorldCommunityGrid](http://worldcommunitygrid.org) is for you.

Comment: [Folding@Home research papers](http://folding.stanford.edu/English/Papers).

Comment: [Folding@Home related awards](http://folding.stanford.edu/English/Awards).

Answer (score 1):

The [BOINC system](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/) has a [page](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/projects.php) of distributed computing projects you can become a member of.

Answer (score 0):

The best ones out there:

- [World Community Grid](https://secure.worldcommunitygrid.org/index.jsp)
- [Folding@Home](http://folding.stanford.edu/)

F@H is closely related to the Stanford university and WCG hosts projects, which most come from universities, too. They both also have quite a good contact to their users for feedback and wanted changes to their software.

Comment: "Best" according to what metric?

Comment: @DanielBeck To my very own? And in addition to that, community effort, scientific research, technical engineering... F@H is one of the technical most finest multithreading apps out there.